# Jquery isn't working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

My problem is that when I call a jquery function, nothing happens or I have an error. 
I also saw with firebug that nothing is called when I press my button that calls it

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "[http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd]">  
<?php // Encodé en UTF-8 (sans BOM) 
 require('basedonnee.php'); 
 $BD = new basedonnee(); 
 session_start(); 
?> 
<html xmlns="[http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml]"> 
<head> 
<title>un titre</title> 
 <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />  
    <meta name="keywords" content="" /> 
    <meta name="description" content="" /> 
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /> 

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="whirlpool.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 function changeMonth(place,nomois) 
 { 
  $j=jQuery.noConflict(); 

  document.getElementById("mois").value = nomois+place 
  $j(document).get("getCalendrier.php?mois=2", function(data){ 
   document.getElementById("calen").innerHTML = data; 
  }); 
 } 
</script> 
</head>
```

This is the beginning of my index.php
My changemonth function is called, I checked. But my .get doesn't work and my getCalendrier.php is never called.

Does someone have an idea to solve my problem?
thanks

Comment: Where's the code that you think is binding a click event to a button?

Comment: If your changeMonth function is never called, then it isn't your .get that isn't working, as it never even gets a chance to execute. Can you post the code that calls changeMonth?

Comment: Haven't work much with jQuery, but isn't `noConflict()` just a special method and you should call `$(document)` instead of ` $j(document)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function changeMonth(place,nomois) 
{ 
    $j=jQuery.noConflict(); 

    document.getElementById("mois").value = nomois+place;

    $j(document).get("getCalendrier.php?mois=2", function(data){ 
        document.getElementById("calen").innerHTML = data; 
    }); 
}
```

You missed a `;` after nomois+place

Comment: You're right and I think that it was only this that was making problems. I can't believe that a single ; could be problem. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `$j(document)` to just `$j` before `.get`:

```
$j.get("getCalendrier.php?mois=2", function(data){ 
    document.getElementById("calen").innerHTML = data; 
});
```

[`jQuery.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) isn't a method of a jQuery collection, it's a (so-to-say) "*static*" function on the jQuery global (similar to `jQuery.noConflict`).

Also, Make sure the current page and `getCalendrier.php` are in the same directory since the URL given is relative to the current URL.

And, to help you with debugging Ajax in your project, most browsers have developer tools with "Network" watching included. Firefox has Firebug, Google Chrome and Safari have it built-in, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I also put a ; at the end of the sentence before.
Now it's working well!
I was also using firebug with google chrome and firefox and the getCalendrier was already at the same place than the index.php

Answer (score 0):

you' re missing a ; here:

```
document.getElementById("mois").value = nomois+place
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("#mois").value = nomois+place;
```

additionally you're missing # id tags when getting an element by id

Comment: The `#` is unecessary. `document.getElementById` with `#` will try to find `<div id="#mois">`, not `<div id="mois">`. The `#` is only needed when using jQuery or [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelector).